# Error after Freeform Pro update to 3.5.10

Tags: plugin-freeform

I am posting this here because the Freeform support form is currently not working.

I get an error when viewing `/admin/freeform/dashboard` and `/admin/freeform/submissions`, however `/admin/freeform/forms` is working. It shows all forms and I can click on them to see the form detail page BUT there seems to be a faulty form - the one with the most submissions. When I click on it the detail page shows up with nothing in it but the title. This request doesn't seem to throw an error in the logs like the others did.

### Versions with error

- Craft: 3.3.16.3 and 3.4.1
- Freeform: 3.5.10

### Versions sans error (current production versions)

- Craft: 3.3.16.3
- Freeform: 3.5.4

It is still working in production right now. The error occurred after doing an update. This is the stack trace for `/admin/freeform/dashboard` and `/admin/freeform/submissions`:

```
2020-01-30 17:56:11 [-][5571][osi4gj30cngblrtejvdpq77h60][error][Error] Error: Call to a member function getForm() on null in /var/www/KLR3/vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/src/Elements/Submission.php:498
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/src/Elements/Submission.php(474): Solspace\Freeform\Elements\Submission->getForm()
#1 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/src/Elements/Submission.php(737): Solspace\Freeform\Elements\Submission->getFieldMetadata()
#2 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/src/Elements/Submission.php(539): Solspace\Freeform\Elements\Submission->getFieldByIdentifier('enabledForSite')
#3 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(558): Solspace\Freeform\Elements\Submission->__set('enabledForSite', '1')
#4 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(Solspace\Freeform\Elements\Submission), Array)
#5 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/src/Elements/Submission.php(156): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#6 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1801): Solspace\Freeform\Elements\Submission->__construct(Array)
#7 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(2809): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->createElement(Array)
#8 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1453): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->_createElements(Array)
#9 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(238): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->populate(Array)
#10 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Query.php(152): yii\db\Query->all(NULL)
#11 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1482): craft\db\Query->all(NULL)
#12 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/src/Controllers/DashboardController.php(23): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->all()
#13 [internal function]: Solspace\Freeform\Controllers\DashboardController->actionIndex()
#14 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#16 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(178): yii\base\Controller->runAction('index', Array)
#17 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('index', Array)
#18 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(290): yii\base\Module->runAction('freeform/dashbo...', Array)
#19 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('freeform/dashbo...', Array)
#20 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(275): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#21 /var/www/KLR3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#22 /var/www/KLR3/public/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#23 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to update to Freeform 3.6+ (Craft 3.4+), which contains a compatibility fix for this issue. :)

https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/setup/changelog.html#_3-6-0-2020-01-23

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Comment: I'm getting this error on Craft 3.4+ and Freeform 3.11, any ideas @solspace?